# Error trying to load ODBC connection to dataset

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable, odbc

I am trying to connect to an ODBC connection.

This works.

```
    Dim cn As OdbcConnection
    cn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;UID=UserName;" &
                            "PWD=Password;DATABASE=dbName;")

    Dim mystring As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo_lData WHERE S_DT > #3/18/2018#"
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(mystring)
    cn.Open()
    MsgBox("Connected")
    cn.Close()
```

I've tried a couple of variations using different code that I've found on the internet, but I keep getting the same error. Error 42000, incorrect syntax near #.  Here is the code.

```
    Dim selectSQL As String = "SELECT * FROM dbo_lData WHERE S_DT > #3/18/2018#"
    cn = New OdbcConnection("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;UID=UserName;" &
                            "PWD=Password;DATABASE=dbName;")
    Dim custDA As New OdbcDataAdapter
    Dim selectCMD As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand(selectSQL, cn)
    custDA.SelectCommand = selectCMD

    Dim custDS As DataSet = New DataSet
    custDA.Fill(custDS, "lData")

    DataGridView1.Visible = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = custDA
```

I'm pretty lost on this, but what I am trying to do is just...

1. Make ODBC Connection
2. Load results, preferable into a datatable
3. Set datagridview.datasource = datatable

Comment: You didnt mention what DB it was, but it apparently doesnt like the `#3/18/2018#`.  Use SQL Parameters (for this reason and many, many others); but the `S_DT` column name is suspicious - it is a Date type column right?  Also take the [tour] and read [ask]

Comment: You also dont need a DataSet and a *local* DataAdapter to fill a DataTable.

Comment: This DataGridView1.DataSource = custDA should be DataGridView1.DataSource = custDS("lData"). Also, as what @Plutonix said, use sql parameters in your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is referring to your Select statement. As the comments said use parameters. First double check the data type of S_DT column. I wonder why you are using ODBC when the SQL server native provider SQLClient will yield better results.

```
Dim cn As New OdbcConnection("connection string")
Dim cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM dbo_lData WHERE S_DT > @sdate", cn)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@sdate", OdbcType.Date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am still a bit confused though.  You have @sdate in the SQL string.  What does the @ symbol mean?  And how is this getting the specific date that I am trying to use as the Where criteria?  Also, you ask why I am using ODBC.  I am connecting to a server and the guy who gave me the credentials told me it's an ODBC connection.  If there is a way to do it using SQLClient that would be better, I would love to know how to do it.  Thanks again.

Comment: Never mind.  I was able to work out how to use SQLClient to get it working.  Thanks.

Comment: The @ is just a convention for naming SQL Server parameters. The Parameters.Add method takes the name of the parameter as it is in the SQL statement. This is a string value thus the "@sdate". the second parameter is the data type. Then outside the parentheses put .Value = the value of the parameter. So glad you were able to use the native client.